# How to index parts of jsonObject by setting custom mappings in Elasticsearch?

Tags: dynamic, indexing, mapping, elasticsearch, json

**I have such a JsonObject:**

```
{
"success": true,
"type": "message",
"body": {
"_id": "5215bdd32de81e0c0f000005",
    "id": "411c79eb-a725-4ad9-9d82-2db54dfc80ee",
    "type": "metaModel",
    "title": "testchang",
    "authorId": "5215bd552de81e0c0f000001",
    "drawElems": [
    {
        "type": "App.draw.metaElem.ModelStartPhase",
        "id": "27re7e35-550j",
        "x": 60,
        "y": 50,
        "width": 50,
        "height": 50,
        "title": "problem engagement",
        "isGhost": true,
        "pointTo": "e88e2845-37a4-4c45-a030-d02a3c3e03f9",
        "bindingId": "90f79d70-0afc-11e3-98d2-83967d2ad9a6",
        "model": "meta",
        "entityType": "phase",
        "domainId": "411c79eb-a725-4ad9-9d82-2db54dfc80ee",
        "authorId": "5215bd552de81e0c0f000001",
        "userData": {},
        "_id": "5215f4c5d89f629c1700000d"
    },
   {...}
  ]
}}
```

I want to index only parts of this object, so I defined an explicit mapping by myself and disabled the dynamic mapping. **here is the mapping:**

```
String mapping=XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject().
startObject("domaindata").field("dynamic","false").
startObject("properties")
.startObject("success").field("type","string").endObject()
.startObject("type").field("type","string").endObject()
.startObject("body").field("type", "object")
.startObject("properties")
.startObject("id").field("type","string").field("store","yes").endObject()
.startObject("type").field("type","string").field("store","yes").endObject()
.startObject("title").field("type","integer").field("store","yes").endObject()
.startObject("drawElems").field("type","nested")
.startObject("properties")
.startObject("type").field("store","yes").field("type","string").endObject()
.startObject("title").field("store","yes").field("type","string").endObject()
.endObject().endObject().endObject().endObject().endObject().endObject().endObject().string();
```

I added this mapping in my index：

```
node.client().admin()
            .indices().prepareCreate("testdomaindata")
            .addMapping("domaindata", mapping)
            .execute().actionGet();
```

and indexed with following code:

```
node.client().prepareBulk().add(node.client()

.prepareIndex("testdomaindata","domaindata",string).setSource(responseDomainData1))

.execute().actionGet();
```

I used the **GetResponse** and Head Plugin to check if the jsonObject is indexed correctly. But the problem is with this mapping, the jsonObject seems to be not indexed at all. 
In head plugin, the index and type has been created but there is no doc in this index and type.

Did I define a incorrect mapping？ Or there are some mistakes in my other codes?
Could anybody give me some advices?
Thanks a lot!

here is the mapping I got in Index metadata:

```
{
domaindata: 

 {
    dynamic: false
    properties: {
        body: {
            properties: {
                id: {
                    store: true
                    type: string
                }
                title: {
                    store: true
                    type: integer
                }
                drawElems: {
                    properties: {
                        title: {
                            store: true
                            type: string
                        }
                        type: {
                            store: true
                            type: string
                        }
                    }
                    type: nested
                }
                type: {
                    store: true
                    type: string
                }
            }
        }
        type: {
            type: string
        }
        success: {
            type: string
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Was the mapping really created? You are using head, so check in the metadata if it was created. And if possible, post it in json form (readability's sake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your mapping correctly, the index wait for a integer for the title field, and you give it a string. Thus, your indexation fail.

Here's hoping it is that simple.
Good luck